# Building Chess game?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to build a basic text chess game. Currently in every array position, i'm trying to enter a 2 character word. P1 is first player's pawn. Its giving me `incompatible pointer to integer conversion` error on the `strcpy` function line.

I tried to use `ChessArray[firstCounter][secCounter] = 'P1';` but it did not work and give me an error.

NOTE: I know a lot of people will say its better to use another language to make this game but i wanted to practice my C skills.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char ChessArray[8][8];
    for (int firstCounter = 0; firstCounter <= 7; firstCounter++)
    {
        for (int secCounter = 0; secCounter <= 7; secCounter++)
        {
            strcpy(ChessArray[firstCounter][secCounter],"p");
        }
    }
    printf(" |A |B |C |D |E |F |G |H |\n");
    for (int firstCounters = 0; firstCounters <= 7; firstCounters++)
    {
        printf("%i", firstCounters);
        for (int secCounters = 0; secCounters <= 7; secCounters++)
        {
            printf("| ");
            printf("%c",ChessArray[firstCounters][secCounters]);
        }
        printf("|");
        printf("%i",firstCounters);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf(" |A |B |C |D |E |F |G |H |\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(ChessArray[firstCounter][secCounter],"p");` can't work: it's not char array. Do `ChessArray[firstCounter][secCounter] = 'p';`

Comment: Please don't confuse form with function. Save the character representations for human consumption, and convert to/from a better representation for internal use. There are 32 chess pieces, you need 32 `enum`s or something similar to represent them internally..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i'm trying to enter "P1" not "p"

Comment: @WeatherVane interesting point. I will reconsider my approach.

Comment: @BassamMetwally or 16 enums, or even fewer, if you consider the pawn as one type, bishop as 2 types, etc. Chess is known to be computationally intensive, so using string descriptions of the pieces for the analysis is going to hit the performance badly.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing a char* and char.  Your ChessArray is an array of array of characters.  Not an array of array of char*.  A string in double quotes is a char*.  A single character in single quotes is a character.  Strcpy works with char*, not with characters, and it can't copy data into a character.  Either you want to make it a char *ChessArray[][], or you want to use ChessArray[firstCounter][secCounter] = 'p'.

Note that if you use the char* ChessArray[][] version you have to allocate the memory each of those char* at each of those indices holds with malloc before you pass it to strcpy the first time.